# Wave packet in curved spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, waves, wave-particle-duality, geodesics

It is known that the classical equation of motion for a scalar field wave packet on a curved spacetime background gives the geodesic trajectory (the e.o.m. is $(\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu + m^2) \Phi=0$). However, I couldn't see that.

How can one derived the geodesic equation from the above e.o.m. ?

Comment: Hint: assume $\phi = \delta(t(\tau))\delta(x(\tau))\delta(y(\tau))\delta(z(\tau))$

Comment: Actually, that's how I first did the problem. No, I don't see how one can get it from there, but there might be away to see that by choosing $\Phi \sim e^{ik^\mu x_\nu}$, then if from something like $k^2 = m^2$ condition one gets $k^\mu \nabla_\mu k^\nu = 0$ (this is the geodesic equation, as $k_\mu \sim u_\mu$, in classical limit), then problem solved.

Comment: Well, $\delta(x) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int e^{ikx}dk$

Comment: in **curved** spacetime?

Comment: Yes, curved spacetime. I want to see how particles (wave packets) can realize the geodesic via the equation of motion.

Comment: I was referring to that formula for the delta fuction based on Fourier transform. It generally fails since no global coordinates exist.

Comment: Can you give a reference for the first sentence of the post, "it is known that...". I've seen the geodesic equation for a point particle, i.e. an equation on a parameterized curve that has interpretation the space-time position as a function of time. I've also seen the KG field (ok I did not study it in curved space-times) and the duality wave-particle came from quantization of the KG field if I'm not mistaken? So I would say that if you want a geodesic equation you should first recover from the field the interpretation of position, somehow a position observable evaluated on a state, not just

Comment: I don't think you can recover the geodesic just from the field equation

Comment: found this http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02817959#page-1

Comment: @user39158 This has been discussed on [usenet](http://sci.tech-archive.net/Archive/sci.physics.relativity/2009-10/msg01634.html) back in the day, but you may find similar discussion in, say, *Aspects of Quantum Field Theory in Curved Spacetime* by Stephen A. Fulling...or *any* introductory book on QFT in curved spacetime.

Answer (score 3):

This is covered (in two pieces) in Chapter 4 of Wald's *General Relativity* for the Maxwell field;  I'll adapt his proof here.

We start with the equation $(\nabla^a \nabla_a + m^2) \Phi = 0$.  Let us look for a solution to this equation of the form
$$
\Phi = \Phi_0 e^{iS},
$$
where $S$ is a real-valued function and $\Phi_0$ is "slowly varying" compared to $S$.  This is the standard sort of "geometrical optics" approximation;  in practical terms,  it means that we can ignore any derivatives of $\Phi_0$.  Thus, we have
$$
\nabla_a \Phi = \Phi_0  e^{iS} (i \nabla_a S)\quad \Rightarrow \quad \nabla^a \nabla_a \Phi + m^2 \Phi = \Phi_0  e^{iS} \left[ m^2 - (\nabla^a S) (\nabla_a S) + i \nabla^a \nabla_a S \right] = 0.
$$
Both the imaginary and real parts of the quantity in square brackets above must vanish:
$$
m^2 = (\nabla^a S) (\nabla_a S), \qquad \nabla^a \nabla_a S = 0.
$$
If we let $k_a = \nabla_a S$, the first equation implies that $k_a k^a = m^2$, as we expect.  Moreover, if we take the derivative of both sides of the first equation, we get
\begin{align*}
0 &= \nabla_b \left[ (\nabla^a S) (\nabla_a S) \right] \\
&= 2 \nabla^a S \nabla_b \nabla_a S && \text{(product rule)} \\
&= 2 \nabla^a S \nabla_a \nabla_b S && \text{(derivatives commute on scalars)} \\
&= 2 k^a \nabla_a k_b,
\end{align*}
and so the vector $k_a$ satisfies the geodesic equation.

Answer (score 1):

As in your comment, make an Ansatz $$ \phi = \exp(i f)$$ where $f$ is an unknown scalar function such that $(df)_\mu (df)^\mu = m^2$. Then the equation of motion for $\phi$ is equivalent to the geodesic equation for $(df)_\mu$.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see why $k^2=m^2$ must imply it's the geodesic equation for $k_\mu$ $(*)$. I think that's where I stuck -- see my later comments above. Would you please show me how $(*)$ can be true?

Comment: You're right. I got ahead of myself and actually what one obtains is that $(df)_\mu$ should have zero divergence.

Comment: Sorry; it might be too trivial for you, but it's not for me. Could you please be more specific about "$(df)_\mu$ has $0$ divergence" and its connection to the geodesic?

Comment: With a $\phi$ of this form the equation of motion is $\exp(if) [ i^2 (df)_\mu (df)^\mu + m^2 + \nabla^\mu (df_\mu) ] = 0$ where $(df)_\mu = \partial_\mu f = \nabla_\mu f$, the latter equality from $f$ being a scalar. When the first two terms cancel, what is left is that $\nabla_\mu \nabla^\mu f = 0$. There is not necessarily a connection to geodesics here. As I said I got ahead of myself and made a mistake. However, many spacetimes admit vector fields that are both divergence-free and geodesic, so in these you can find solutions of the form specified, and the gradient of $f$ will be geodesic.

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't make sense to me why the first 2 term must cancel. I mean, why don't $f$ has a form so that $\nabla^\mu \nabla_\mu f$ is non-zero and both of them cancel? Moreover, I still don't see why the last equation goes to $0$ indicates geodesic equation yet.

Comment: PS: I've just read your edited comment. Thank you so much for your help! I'm still waiting for a more complete answer, since I think there should be one.

Comment: Also, there must be some physical meanings for the geodesic solution, which isn't very clear to me right now.